# Google Script Running Off Incorrect Timezone

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

My google script is currently running off of a GMT-5 timezone, when I am located in the UK. I have tried on different devices where the IP shows that I am in the UK, but it still runs as if in New York. Is there a way to set the timezone to GMT in the sheet or with a line of code? I have seen there is a way of going into the project preferences, but with the new IDE version of the script editor I cannot find this option. I have already set the sheet's own timezone to UK.

This happened overnight, as previously and in previous version it was running off of the correct timezone. Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

Sorted this myself. Easy way to globally change the timezone, but had to revert back to the legacy script editor as could not find the option to change timezone in the new one. For some reason, the timezone was globally set to GMT+5.